# Divs overlap navbar

Tags: html, css

I know that multiple questions has been discussed on this subject, I coped and pasted every suggestion/answers.. None of them work, please help!
Remember I would like the content, when scrolled to not overlap the menubar.

**My Problem**

[Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9gey.jpg)

When ever I scroll the center div(the one that says "this website is dedicated to games") overlaps the menu bar.
How do I prevent this from happening?

[Here's another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHqSj.jpg)

**Code Id(s)**

Center div that is colored black. id="divCenter".
Element that is being overlapped("menu bar). id="NavDivef"

**Code, html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home:</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Video-Game-Wallpapers-and-Backgrounds-0.jpg">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="nav">
            <div id="maindic">
                <div id="NavDivef">
                    <ul>
                        <h1>CPG</h1>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Find out more</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Find out more</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <center>
           <div id="divCenter">
              <p>
                This website is dedicated to games.
              </p>
           </div>
        </center>
        <img alt="" id="gameImage"  src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Video-Game-Wallpapers-and-Backgrounds-0.jpg"/>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code, css**

```
body{
   font-family: arial, sens-serif;
   background-size: cover;
}
*{
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;  
}  
#NavDivef ul{
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   background-color: black;
   line-height: 80px;
   position: fixed;
   line-height: 80px;
   opacity: 0.8;
} 
#NavDivef ul li{        
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   float: right; 
}
#NavDivef ul a{
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 30px;
   color:White;     
}
#NavDivef ul li:hover{
   background: orangered;
   color: #cc0000;
}
#NavDivef h1{
   color:red;
   width: 300px;
   float: left;
   font-size: 480%;
   margin-left: 15px;
}
#divCenter{
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height: 54%; 
   background-color: black;
   margin-top: 280px;
   margin-left: 350px;
}
#divCenter p{
   color:red;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-left: 30px;
   font-size: 40px;
}     
#divExample{
   width: 600px;
   height: 700px
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow - please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question - for instance, what exactly is the expected/desired behaviour?

Comment: Because it is absolutely positioned in document. I'd suggest you to look for and use a framework such as [bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/). If you're happy with absolute positioning, you may better play with z-index property. Oh here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgaw9cwo/) btw, if someone is willing to do smth.

Comment: if you want o maintain same distance between menubar and divCenter, you can use the position:fixed and top:130px(which you can adjust accordingly)
#divCenter{
 position: fixed;
   width: 50%;
   height: 54%; 
   background-color: black;
  margin-left: 350px;   
  top:130px;
}

Comment: @SeaKiller, Try giving `#NavDivef ul` css property: `z-index:999;`. But best practice would be to give it to the `nav#nav`, but since you have not added any property to `nav#nav` so giving z-index to that wouldn't work. To use `z-inedx` you must specify `position` property.

Comment: I got it to work finally. 1:00 o clock in the morning. Thxs for you help!